# SQL AS query results in duplicate column

Tags: sql, case

I have a SQL query like so

```
SELECT
    name,
    CASE WHEN (new_value=2) THEN 0 END as out,
    CASE WHEN (previous_value=2) THEN 1 END as out
    FROM my_table;
```

This results in duplicate columns:

```
name out  out
foo   1   null
bar   null  1
```

instead of

```
name out
foo   1 
bar   0
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want one `case` expression with two conditions:

```
SELECT name,
       (CASE WHEN new_value = 2 THEN 0 
             WHEN previous_value = 2 THEN 1
        END) as out
FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
SELECT
    name,
    CASE 
        WHEN new_value = 2 THEN 0 
        WHEN previous_value = 2 THEN 1 
    END as out
FROM my_table;
```

In your query, each `case` expression generates one column in the resulset. You want only one, with two branches (denoted by `when ... then ...`)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `null` output, so you need to add `else` on this.

```
select name,
    case 
        when new_value = 2 then 0 
        when previous_value = 2 then 1 
    else 0 end as out
from my_table;
```